# Google Chrome regularly resets all sessions when closing and opening it again

Tags: google-chrome, session

When using Google Chrome, it frequently happens that between restarts (or quitting and starting Chrome again), Chrome loses virtually all sessions and cookies. I have to log back into every single website and process all cookie notifications, etc. Since this is a work computer, I have to do this for many websites (often daily) which is quite frankly obnoxious as hell. This doesn’t happen on *every* restart, but way too frequently.

- The setting “Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows” (Settings → Privacy and security → Cookies and other site data) is turned off.
- The computer was set-up with Ubuntu by myself. There is no employer-controlled software on it. I can use it just like the Ubuntu OS on my personal computer.
- Google Chrome was completely purged from the system and set-up anew. The issue persists.

What other settings or conditions could possibly influence this? I don’t really have the luxury to switch browsers because I need all available browsers for testing.

---

Logging events to detect a possible regularity in interval:

- 2021-10-22 09:05 (right after Google Chrome updated from 94.0.4606.81-1 to 95.0.4638.54-1, see [chrome releaselog](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2021/10/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_19.html))
- 2021-10-27 07:55 (no Google Chrome update)
- 2021-10-29 09:07 (right after Google Chrome updated from 95.0.4638.54-1 to 95.0.4638.69-1, see [chrome releaselog](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2021/10/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_28.html))
- 2021-11-10 16:48 (Chrome just crashed and all cookies were deleted upon restart despite me clicking restore)
- 2021-11-16 07:52 (right after Google Chrome updated from 95.0.4638.69-1 to 96.0.4664.45-1, see [chrome releaselog](https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2021/11/stable-channel-update-for-desktop.html))

This logging of events turned out to be fruitless. While every Chrome update seems to definitely trigger the issue, the issue isn’t isolated to times when a Chrome update was installed.